# Mapbox GL JS getBounds undefined

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I've been trying to get use Mapbox GL JS to plot multiple markers and have the map fitBounds on those markers. The markers plot fine on the map, Im just having trouble with the fitBounds part.

I keep on getting this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined
lng_lat_bounds.js:154
```

Here is my JS to plot the markers.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
    center: [-96.2, 37.8],
    zoom: 9
});

// add markers to map
var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
for ( var i=0; i < markersArray.length; ++i ){

    markersArray[i].features.forEach(function(marker) {

        // create a HTML element for each feature
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';

        // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}) // add popups
                .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
            .addTo(map);
    });
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to actually extend those bounds for each marker lng,lat with [bounds.extend](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds#extend).